# Multiple arrays with malloc

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, struct

I am initializing a struct called Array which consists of an array of Items and an int to keep track of the number of the Items.

```
  typedef struct anything{
    char text[MAXI];
    int any;
  }Item;

  typedef struct array{
    Item arr[0];
    int size;
  }Array;
```

To initialize the Array, I'm using malloc and returning the pointer.

```
Array create(){
    Array *p1 = malloc(sizeof(Array));
    p1->size = 0;
    return *p1;
}
```

The problem I have is that some functions are designed for 2 Arrays, such as intersection:

```
Array intersection(Array S,Array T){
    int i, j;
    Array I = create();
    for(i=0; i<(S.size); i++){
        for(j=0; j<(T.size); j++){
            if((compStructs(S.arr[i], T.arr[j])) == true)
                add(I, S.arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return I;
}
```

According to this code, if I were to execute create() twice, I would lose the pointer to the first array. Is there something I can do in the main program to prevent this, or what modifications can I do to the current function?

Edit: Added the add item function:

```
void add(Array S,Item x){

bool rep = false;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<(S.size); i++){
        if(compStructs(x,S.arr[i]) == true)
            rep = true;
    }
    if(rep == false){
            Item *p2 = realloc(S.arr, sizeof(Item));
            *p2 = x;
            (S.size)++;
    }
    else
        printf("The item is already in the set.");

}
```

My main problem is that I'm not sure how to call two seperate arrays which are to be created at the user's request. The program is in it's build up but currently it looks somehitng like this:

```
#include "array.h"
Item x;

void arraymenu(){
    char inp;
    while((inp = getchar())!= '\n'){
        printf("a. To Create a new Array\n"
                "b. To Add a new Item\n"
                "c. To Remove an Item\n"
                "d. To Clear all contents of the Array\n"
                "e. To Get the size of the Array\n"
                "f. To Get a list of the number of elements of your choice\n"
                "g. To Check whether the array is empty\n"
                "h. To Get the union of two sets\n"
                "i. To Get the intersection of two sets\n"
                "j. To Get the difference of two sets\n"
                "k. To Check if a set is the subset of the other one\n"
                "l. To map a function to all Items of an Array\n"
                "m. To apply a function to all Items of an Array\n"
                "n. To store the Array in a File\n"
                "o. To load the Array from a File\n"   );

        switch(inp){
            case 'a' :  printf("Array A has been created.");
                        Array A = create();
                        break;

            case 'b' :  printf("Enter any integer, followed by any string.");
                        scanf("%d", &x.any);
                        scanf("%s", &x.text);
                        add(A, x);
                        break;

            case 'c' :  printf("Enter the integer and string you wish to remove ");
                        scanf("%d", &x.any);
                        scanf("%s", &x.text);
                        removee(A,x);
                        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the size field coming after the array?  And don't you want to malloc it with a larger size, rather than an array with enough space for zero elements?

Comment: The size field is used to know what size the Item arr[] is. I'm using malloc with 0 elements, since I'm using realloc in another function to add an item. Will edit it in if needed.

Comment: Without wanting to sound arrogant, you might want to read up on the difference (and point of) _pointers_ vs _arrays_ `Item arr[0]` just doesn't really make sense. Also: a `malloc` wrapper function _should_, IMO return what `malloc` returns: a pointer

Comment: `According to this code, if I were to execute create() twice` - where in this code would you be calling `create()` twice? You create the new array once before the loops, why would you change that?

Comment: @user2035045: right so how do you know where to find the size field, since it comes after the flexible array member?  This makes little sense--everybody who does stuff like this puts the size first, data second.

Comment: I would call create() twice in the main program.
The user may want to create an array and fill it with a set of items. He may then want to create another array and fill with a different set of items. Therefore create() would ahve to be called twice.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: not really, though... if you have a couple of structs with a pointer (not an array, but a pointer, like I suggest in my answer at the bottom), putting that pointer first allows for more generic allocation and free function to be used (eg linked lists)

Comment: each time you call `add` you reallocate `arr` to `sizeof(Item)`...1 item...if you want more items you have to multiply the size by the number of items

Comment: The add function is designed to only add 1 Item at a time.

Comment: @user2035045: You don't understand: you're not _adding_ anything see the end of my answer: realloc needs to specify _the total new size_ you need: `realloc(void *, (current_size + add_size) * sizeof(type));`

Comment: Ok, I should have got the realloc concept clear now. What I'm still not sure about is for example, in the main program in case b when calling the add function, can I let the user chose which array to add to?

Comment: @user2035045: you could `int which; scanf(" %d", &which); if (which == 1) /* use first array */ else /*use other*/`, but then why would you? where you store the input is up to you. If you let the user choose that sort of stuff, then you'll have to write tons of `if-else` branches... just don't bother. Where you store something is up  to you, not the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, instead of a derefferenced pointer to a variable *local to a given function's scope* you need to return a pointer (BTW, compiling `return *ptr` should give a warning when compiling, add `-Wall`, and don't ignore what the compiler is telling you):

```
Array *create()
{
    Array *a_ptr = malloc(sizeof(*a_ptr));
    if (a_ptr == NULL) exit (EXIT_FAILURE);//failed to allocate memory
    a_ptr->size = 0;
    return a_ptr;
}
```

To be called like this:

```
Array *S, *T;
S = create();
T = create();
```

Now you have 2 arrays ready to play with. Note that you'll need to *either* dereference these pointers, or use the indirection operator on them always:

```
(*S).size = 1;
//or
S->size += 123;
```

You'll also probably want to change `intersection` to something like:

```
Array *intersection(Array *S,Array *T)
{
    int i, j;
    Array *I = create();
    for(i=0; i<(S->size); ++i)
    {
        for(j=0; j<(T->size); ++j)
            if(compStructs(S.arr[i], T.arr[j])) add(I, S.arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return I;
}
```

Of course, once you're done with all of these `Array` structs, you'll have to `free()` them, too.

As far as `compStructs` and `add` go, I expect you'll have to work on those functions, too. While you're at it, perhaps change the struct to better fit the way you're using it:

```
typedef struct array
{
    Item *arr;
    size_t size;//size_t makes more sense here
  }Array;
```

Of course, this in turn requires a bit more work when `free`-ing the memory, so a generic free function is advisable:

```
void free_array(Array **a)
{//pointer to pointer
    while((*a)->size--) free((*a)->arr+(*a)->size);
    free(*a);
    *a = NULL;//NULL pointers are safer
}
//call like so:
free_array(&Array_ptr);//yes, address of pointer
```

And `realloc` calls should look something like:

```
realloc(a->arr, (a->size + 1)*sizeof(*(a->arr)));
a->size += 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct array{
    int size;
    Item arr[];
}Array;

Array *create(int size){
    Array *p1 = malloc(sizeof(Array) + size*sizeof(Item));
    if(p1)p1->size = size;
    //return *p1;//memory leak
    return p1;
}
```